# URL-Alias redirect

Tags: nodes, uri, redirection

A few days ago I made a mistake and I lost all my rankings during the weekend.(Google Sandboxed - duplicate pages )
Google indexed my website with eg."node/123" instead with the "URL-Alias".
I changed everything and my site is working like it was before.

But how can I reindex my website with my old URL-Alias or to remove the e.g "node/123"

Do I have to set an 301 redirect from "node/..." -> URL-Alias?
Or is the URL -Alias already a 301 redirect and it will be done automatically?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should use [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module

Answer (score 0):

It depends what module you are using, if you are using [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto), then no, you don't need to worry about reindexing your site.

To double check if your site is already using a 301 on it's redirect, you can open the page your looking for in chrome with the inspector window open. Click on the network tab and then go to your redirected page (node/123). If node/123 shows up with a status of 301, your good. Google will follow that and update it's page rankings accordingly (see picture for what your looking for).

[image]